# php mysql best practice show selected in dropdown

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, selected

I have a fairly simple problem.  I have a select dropdown with values 1 to 10.  This is an edit screen so users have already chosen a value that should be selected.  I am giving them the chance to change it.  So all I need to do is insert the word selected in the option value.  To accomplish this simple task, I have been doing a bunch of inelegant if thens.  Is there a best practice or simple way to do this.  It seems unnecessary overhead to do all these if thens and create 10 new variables.  Note for reasons of keeping html separate from php logic, I do not want to write the option values out sequentially  I have the html in a separate area and just need to set the variable selected in the appropriate places.

```
if ($row['points']==1){
$select1 = "selected"}
if ($row['points']==2){
$select2 = "selected"}
//values 3 through 9
if ($row['points']==2){
$select2 = "selected"}


echo '<select name="points">';
echo '<option value = 1'. $select1.'>1</option>';
echo '<option value=2'. $select1.'>2</option>';
//values 3 through 9
echo '<option value=10'.$select10.'>10</option>';
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using single selectable list (no multiple selected allowed) i.e. so only one can be selected at once.. look for http://fi.php.net/str_replace

```
echo str_replace("value='".$selected_value."'", "value='".$selected_value."' selected", "<option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option> ....");
```

Comment: This has the advantage of working for name=strings.  The looped approaches above are nice as well if the names are numeric.

Answer (score 3):

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
   echo "<option value=$x" . ($row['points'] == $x ? ' selected' : '')
      . ">$x</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

a for loop is good for this, with an inline if else statement to test the selected case

```
echo '<select name="points">';
for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
   echo "<option value='{$i}'".($row['points']==$i ? ' select="selected"':'').">{$i}</option>";   

}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 1):

I do it with jquery and a hidden field that inidcates the selected value of a `<select>`.

html:

```
<input type=hidden name=points value=1>
<select name="points">
  <option value=1>1</option>
  <option value=2>2</option>
</select>
```

js:

```
$('input[type=hidden]').each(function(){
            var e = $(this);
            var name = e.attr("name");
            var val = e.val();
            if(name!="")
            {
                e.parent().find('select[name='+name+']').val(val);              
            }       
        });
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/wBVxx/)